# Rotating proxies in if statement (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making a program which goes to a url, clicks a button, checks if the page gets forwarded and if it does saves that url to a file.
However, after a couple of entries the page blocks you from doing anything. When this happens the URL changes and you'll get this `Block.aspx?c=475412`

The program now knows when it's landed on the "blocked" page, I want for it to retry with proxies from `proxies.txt`. I've found a way to use proxies but I have no idea how to "rotate" them after let's say 5 tries or until it dies.

My code
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

```
url_list = open("path").read().split('\n')
proxy_list = open("path").read().split('\n')

try:
    #proxies
    prox = Proxy()
    prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    prox.http_proxy = proxy_list
    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

    #site
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\python\\chromedriver", desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    driver_url = driver.current_url
    for url in url_list:
       driver.get(url)
       send = driver.find_element_by_id("NextButton")
       send.click()

       #if error
    if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='Error']")):
         print("Error class found")

    if "Block.aspx?" in driver_url:
         driver.close()



except ValueError:
    print("Something went wrong checking the URL.")
```

Now where I want to implement it is here

```
    if "Block.aspx?" in driver_url:
         driver.close()
```

instead of `driver.cose()` ideally, I'd want the program to use a new proxy from `proxies.txt` and when it goes to the blocked page again, use a new one from the list. I have no clue as to how I'd implement this at all and I've googled it a bit but I am unable to find anything on this matter.

**now for my other part of the question**

I have these if statements for when there's an error message found and when the site is blocked

```
   #if error
if (driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='Error']")):
     print("Error class found")

if "Block.aspx?" in driver_url:
        driver.close()
```

what'd be the correct way to check if the page gets forwarded to a new one?

again, thanks so much for helping me everyone I'm a newcomer when it comes to programming and I am unable to find anything on these issues.

I've been looking and am yet to find and answer

edit: Still haven't found anything

edit2: I still am yet to find a way to do this

Comment: This program will only be used on sites that I am allowed to use it on

Comment: You mentioned you want to pull a new proxy from `proxy_list`, but in your `ChromeDriver` declaration, you are assigning the entire `proxy_list` to `prox.http_proxy`. Is this intentional?

Comment: It's not about getting the data, I'm making this to (hopefully) prevent this from happening in the future and what measures I can take. This program will only be used on my own site/host.

Comment: I am aware of this, and this is used on MY site (i own the server too).

Comment: You'd have to close the browser and open a new one with the new proxy. Or you could just use a proxy rotator service if you're serious enough.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to just route the next request to the server with a proxy